# T-SQL Find a date in multiple date ranges

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables that I need to get information from. One table has a code that I need to insert into another table. A third table ties these together.

Table one has a person ID number, a session number, a transaction date and a code. Some of the codes in this table are blank, so they need to be updated.

Table two has the same information as table one with an extra field of PaymentType.

Table three has the same data as table one with a PaymentType number, a date and a code to update to table one where the code is null.

The TransactionDate in table one need to match the Date or within date ranges in table three.

If the dates in table three are 2015-05-03, 2015-05-14 and 2015-05-30, how can I find a specific date within either of those ranges? If the date in table one is 2015-05-10, I need to find which date range it is in so that I can update table three with the proper code.

```
CREATE TABLE TableThree (
   PersonNumber      VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  ,SessionNumber     VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,transaction_Dates DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Code              VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO 
    TableThree (PersonNumber, SessionNumber, transaction_Dates, Code) 
VALUES 
    ('ABC03854','590','2015-12-21','AAA')
    ,('ABC03862','591','2015-12-10','AAA')
    ,('ABC03862','591','2015-12-21','BBB')
    ,('ABC03893','595','2015-12-02','FFF')
    ,('ABC03893','595','2015-12-30','AAA')
    ,('ABC03970','597','2015-12-21','MMM')
    ,('ABC03976','598','2015-12-10','FFF')
    ,('ABC08931','519','2015-12-10','FFF')
    ,('ABC08931','519','2015-12-21','AAA')
    ,('ABC08931','519','2015-12-30','MMM');

CREATE TABLE mytable (
   PersonNumber     VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  ,SessionNumber    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,transaction_date VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL
  ,CODE             VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO 
    mytable (PersonNumber,SessionNumber,transaction_date,CODE) 
VALUES 
    ('ABC03854',590,'2014-12-23 00:00:00.000',NULL)
    ,('ABC03862',591,'2014-12-16 00:00:00.000',NULL)
    ,('ABC03893',595,'2014-12-16 00:00:00.000',NULL)
    ,('ABC08931',519,'2015-12-22 00:00:00.000',NULL);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You really need to provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Table 3 has all the columns of Table 2 with an extra column, Table 2 has all the columns of Table 1 with an extra column, to me this looks like a proper messed up schema.

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Table one: 
 PersonNumber SessionNumber transaction_date CODE
 ABC03845 590  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000    NULL
 ABC03846 591  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000    NULL
 ABC03850 595  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000    NULL

Comment: Hope this clarifies. I need to find out where the date on table one falls within table three so I can use the CODE field.

Table one: 
PersonNumber SessionNumber transaction_date                CODE
ABC03854         590                 2014-12-23 00:00:00.000    NULL
ABC03862         591                 2014-12-16 00:00:00.000    NULL
ABC03893         595                 2014-12-16 00:00:00.000    NULL
ABC08931         519                        2015-12-22 00:00:00.000    NULL

Comment: Table three:
PersonNumber SessionNumber transaction_Dates   Code
ABC03854         590                         2015-12-21              AAA
ABC03862         591                         2015-12-10              AAA
ABC03862         591                         2015-12-21              BBB
ABC03893         595                         2015-12-02              FFF
ABC03893         595                         2015-12-30              AAA

Comment: ABC03970         597                         2015-12-21              MMM
ABC03976         598                         2015-12-10              FFF
ABC08931         519                         2015-12-10              FFF
ABC08931         519                         2015-12-21              AAA
ABC08931         519                         2015-12-30              MMM